# PHP: optional capturing group

Tags: php, regex

I have two types of expressions:

- abc
- abc (explanation)

I would like to be able to capture both *main text* and *explanation [in parentheses], if present*.

I am trying to use the following regex:

```
preg_match("/(.*?)\\s*(\\(.*\\))*/u", $text, $matches);
```

But it's not working. **How do I make it work?**

Comment: in quotes or parentheses?

Comment: @revo In parentheses. Tnx for noting!

Comment: `preg_match_all("/([^( ]+)\\s*(\\(.*\\))?/u", "abc (test)\nabc", $matches);` https://3v4l.org/FLB0S

Comment: [It is not Java.](https://3v4l.org/n7mDg) @4castle

Comment: @revo `\bTest\b` will be interpreted as backspace characters instead of word-boundary characters.

Comment: @4castle: [Not in PHP](http://ideone.com/uK1EAN). PHP is more lenient to  unknown escape sequences in double quoted literals. Even as for the backslash, one needs 4 backslashes to denote a literal ``\`` in a regex pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting. Regex101 auto-escapes it in the code generator tool.

Comment: There is no [`\b` escape character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in PHP which denotes a backspace. Wait, do you mean conflicts?! @4castle

Comment: @revo I was looking at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) where it mentioned `\b` could mean different things in different contexts. It does mean a backspace, but only in a character class. My mistake.

Comment: Alright. I just don't know who upvotes your comments. @4castle

Comment: @revo Who knows, deleting fixes it though

Comment: @4castle: *Regex101 auto-escapes it in the code generator tool.* And it is correct since to write a literal ``\`` in any PHP string literal, you need to use double backslashes, see [*Strings PHP manual*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). When you write `"/\s/"`, the PHP engine sees it as an invalid escape sequence, and treats as a ``\`` + `s`. So, regex101 is formally right, but the fact is that in fact that is not necessary. I have no idea what is "quicker", but - I think - the performance is not a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are coming from Java you have this habit to stringify a Regular Expression but you should know PHP differs in this way: You don't need to.

The reason why your regex returns empty result is that engine is satisfied at the very first step: `(.*?)`.

You may want to change it to `([^(]+)(\(.*\))?` which doesn't use a lazy or greedy dot `.` quantifier (stops at the right position). If `abc` part always contains word characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, then there is a better pattern to follow: `(\w+)\s*(\(.*\))?`

I'm not sure about used `u` unicode modifier. If you really need it then add it.

```
preg_match("/(\w+)\s*(\(.*\))?/", "abc (explanation)", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "abc (explanation)"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "(explanation)"
}
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/JLOAZ)

Comment: The space should also be optional if the parentheses part isn't there. You can use a non-capturing group: `([^(]+)(?:\s+(\(.*\)))?`

Comment: Thanks. Moved spaces. @4castle

Comment: I recommended the non-capturing group so that the spaces wouldn't be part of the capture group, but `\s*` works fine too if the space isn't required.

Comment: By this pattern `[^(]+` a try to catch any further spaces - which is never going to happen - was useless. I just removed it. @4castle

Comment: @revo Thanks for a thorough explanation. I do appreciate to have an opportunity to learn from you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
preg_match("/.*?\s*(\(.*?\))*$/u", $text, $matches)
```